# How to secure JS Applications with Jquery or Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I developed a Complete SPA application with jquery with ajax like asana.
In this app, including some features like,
Listing Users, 
When clicking a user loading his tasks,
When clicking a specific task loading the task details . etc...

I completed all the development parts with jquery,
But When a user clicking a task from my app, I collecting the task id from an html element attribute and sent to ajax php page.

We can change the attribute value with firebug easily. After that clicking the task name its collecting a wrong value.

How can I solve this type of Security issues with jquery.

Comment: Not at all. Never trust the client/user data.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Y  are you marked this as duplicate, Thos logics are both different.

Comment: It's the same idea. You can't trust nor secure client-side.

Comment: but many js websites overcome this kind of issues, eg :https://trello.com/